How to have optional flavors in Gradle for Android
I am trying to find a way to have optional flavors without being forced to have a "disabled" flavor of the same dimension.
For example, I have defined some dimensions and flavors here:
flavorDimensions flavors.flavorDefaultDimension, "featureX", "featureXType"
productFlavors {
    product {
        dimension flavors.flavorDefaultDimension
        getIsDefault().set(true)
    }

    noX{
        dimension "featureX"
        getIsDefault().set(true)
    }
    x{ dimension "featureX" }

    noType {
        dimension "featureXType"
        getIsDefault().set(true)
    }
    udp { dimension "featureXType" }
    serial { dimension "featureXType" }

}


The rules that I want are:

x featureX dimension is optional, meaning it can be enabled or not present at all.
The featureXType dimension upd and serial is only combined with x featureX dimension when enabled.
If no x is enabled then udp and serial must not be combined. In sort, featureXType dimension is only used for featureX

In the variant filter I use:
// Filter flavors that we do not want
variantFilter { variant ->
    def names = variant.flavors*.name
    // Ignore builds where `Udp` or `Serial` is used without `x`
    if ((names.contains("udp") || names.contains("serial")) && names.contains("noX")) {
        setIgnore(true)
    }
    // Ignore build `noType` with `x`
    if (names.contains("noType") && names.contains("x")) {
        setIgnore(true)
    }
}

This produce the following Build Variants:
productNoXNoTypeDebug
productNoXNoTypeRelease
productXUdpDebug
productXUdpRelease
productXSerialDebug
productXSerialRelease

but I would like to have:
productDebug
productRelease
productXUdpDebug
productXUdpRelease
productXSerialDebug
productXSerialRelease

As you can see I want all the default dimensions to be removed from the final flavors so that it is simpler for a user to read it.
Is there a better way to have optional flavors without forcing to have a "noSomething" flavor just to have the flavor disabled?
I have checked missing Dimension Strategy article: https://kiranrao.in/blog/2020/03/31/gradle-missing-flavors/
but I dont understand how this will solve the problem.
In addition, I have seen something called Feature Flags in gradle to enable or disable features for specific flavor?
For a given set of flavors if a feature is enabled, then add this feature name in the final flavor and build variant. How can I do this?
